# How to automatically add date to output file generated in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using Terminal to run ffmpeg commands (Mac OS) in order to record radio shows streamed online. The stream is in m3u8 I want to output it in mp3. So far so good, I am able to achieve that. However, I'd like the output file to read `YYYYMMDD-fm93-segal.mp3` where `YYYYMMMDD` are the date the recording was made.

I am not able to achieve this using `-strftime 1` for some reason. When using my code, the output file reads `%Y%m&d-fm93-segal.mp3` instead of replacing the strings by the real date.

Here is the line I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://cogecomedia.leanstream.co/cogecomedia/CJMFFM.stream/playlist.m3u8" -acodec mp3 -strftime 1 "%Y%m%d-fm93-segal.mp3"
```

Anyone knows why and could help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

`-strftime` is not a generic option, but is only supported by some muxers: hls, image, segment.

One method is to use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) and give it a big `-segment_time` value if desired:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://cogecomedia.leanstream.co/cogecomedia/CJMFFM.stream/playlist.m3u8" -f segment -segment_time 24:00:00 -acodec mp3 -strftime 1 "%Y%m%d-fm93-segal.mp3"
```

Comment: would that help me set a duration? Let's say I want this recording to run for 60 minutes and then quit?

Comment: @MaximeRichard Add `-t 01:00:00` or `-t 3600`.